# ERROR 2003 (HY000) while trying to connect to mysql remotely

Tags: php, mysql, linux, unix, database-administration

I am trying to connect to mysql remotely. Because this is such a common question I read several tutorials/questions but I keep getting this error:

`ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'the-ip-address' (60)`

I edited the /etc/mysql/my.cnf and commented the line of bind_address like this:

`#bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

After that I ran:

`$ sudo service mysql restart`

with the output of:

`mysql stop/waiting
mysql start/running, process 9853`

mysql is running on default port: 3306

Using the user with which I am trying to connect remotely is working locally on the server (I can connect to the mysql from the server).

In phpmyadmin I configure these users:

`user@localhost
user@127.0.0.1
user@87.45.34.23`

Then I am trying to connect with the following:

`mysql -u user -p -h 87.45.34.23`

Maybe I am missing something... Thank you in advanced

**UPDATE**
As @Geoffrey suggested in the comments the problem was with a firewall. For this reason I will accept his answer although the answer itself is not for that but in the comments he was right.

Comment: which IP have your DB an your remote machine. You must create a user with the remote ip *user@remote-ip" and connect with mysql -uuser -s -h dbatabase-ip

Comment: 87.45.34.23 is the ip where my database is working on

Comment: then the user account is not correct "user@87.45.34.23". you must create one with the remote ip "user@remote-ip" or one "user@%" for any ip

Comment: The error MySQL presents when there is an invalid user or password is either `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ...` or `ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect...` when the host is not authorized. `ERROR 2003 (HY000)` is a complete failure to communicate with the server.

Comment: I tried with you suggestion to set 0.0.0.0 as bind address but it's again not working.

Comment: Check for a local firewall, `iptables -nvL INPUT`, it might be restricting access to port 3306. Also ensure MySQL has actually bound to the port (`netstat -nvlp | grep mysql`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection refused means the MySQL server is not listening or is firewalled.

By commenting out the bind line, MySQL doesn't bind to anything and only allows local socket access, you need to bind it to either the local IP, or all IPs by specifying `0.0.0.0`

Also ensure that `skip-networking` is not set anywhere.

Comment: the user account and the ip from the client are the same. so it look that he connect  to the remote machine and there is no MySQL server

Comment: If MySQL is only bound to the local unix socket, connection even via loopback (`127.0.0.1`) will fail since it is not bound, user privileges have nothing to do with it at this point as the error clearly states `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server` and not `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user`.

Comment: no - the bind is a comment "#bind-address = 127.0.0.1", so the bind is the default IP 0.0.0.0

Comment: sorry my mistake **Debian and Ubuntu, the default bind_address is 127.0.0.1** - i have upvote